# DRF: SearchField for custom queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `get_queryset()` overwritten method in my ModelViewSet class - it returns a queryset with filter by user.

So I need implement a SearchFilter search not only in queryset, returned by `get_queryset` method (`Follow.objects.filter(following=self.request.user)`), but in all values from model - in `Follow.objects.all()`

This is my class:

```
class FollowViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = Follow.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ("user__username", "following__username")

    def perform_create(self, serializer: Serializer) -> Follow:
        following = self.request.data.get("following")
        if not following:
            raise ParseError(
                detail="following must be transfered",
                code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        if self.request.user.get_username() == following:
            raise ParseError(
                detail="User cant follow himself",
                code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        return Follow.objects.filter(following=self.request.user)
```